# Matlab: Gradient descent on Symbolic expression

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

Is there a way to do gradient descent to solve a few parameters in an equation represented as a symbolic expression?

For example, I have the following symbolic equation:

```
a*x + b*y + c*z - 5 = 0
```

I have a *1000 xyz* data points, that I would like to use to minimize to solve for `a`,`b` and `c`. I know I can use the `fitnlm` function, but I'd like to stick to using the symbolic toolbox (as my equation is a lot more complex)